# Emulate behavior of getElementById of IE7

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, polyfills

### Background

I have a web application that currently runs on the Edge Internet Explorer mode. I want to port this application to modern browsers like Edge or Chrome.

The JavaScript in this application relys on IE7 doc mode (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/ie11-deploy-guide/img-ie11-docmode-lg). For example, this application uses  `getElementById()` heavyly, and it assumes that `getElementById()` performs a *case-insensitive* match on *both the ID and NAME* attributes.

### Problem

Of course, you can rewrite this application based on the specs of `getElementById()` in modern JavaScript API. But this application has so many JavaScript files, that it will require a fair amount of non-obvious work. So I am looking for some workarounds.

### Question

Is there any way to emulate the behavior of `getElementById()` of IE7 doc mode on modern browsers?

For example, how to reverse-polyfill the behavior of `getElementById()` to imitate the behavior of it on IE7?

Comment: Sure, just overwrite `document.getElementById` with the legacy behaviour you want?

Comment: This isn't a great answer, but your problem is frustrating enough that I would try it. Use sed and awk or whatever other regex to go through and change every single value you care about to lowercase. It may have to go through and find duplicates and bring them to your attention to manually fix first.

Comment: FWIW, I'd suggest *not* replacing `document.getElementById`. Instead, use your own function. With modern tools (such as those Matt mentioned but also many others) you can readily change all occurrences of `document.getElementById` with your function's name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get a list of all elements which **might** have the name or id that you want, and then filter them to find the first one that matches.

```js
const getElementCaseInsensitivelyByNameOrId = (nameOrId) => {
  // Start by getting a list of prospective elements.
  const prospectiveElements = document.querySelectorAll("[id], [name]");

  // Convert to an array for access to the methods on array.prototype
  const arrayProspectiveElements = [...prospectiveElements];

  // Lower case the search term
  const searchTerm = nameOrId.toLowerCase();

  // Perform the search
  const firstMatch = arrayProspectiveElements.find(element => element.id?.toLowerCase() === searchTerm || element.name?.toLowerCase() === searchTerm);

  return firstMatch;
};

const foo = getElementCaseInsensitivelyByNameOrId("FOO");
const bar = getElementCaseInsensitivelyByNameOrId("BAR");
const sirNotAppearingInThisDocument = getElementCaseInsensitivelyByNameOrId("sirNotAppearingInThisDocument");

console.log({
  foo,
  bar,
  sirNotAppearingInThisDocument
});
```

```html
<div id="Foo">Foo</div>
<input name="bAR" value="bAR">
```

Or, more concisely:

```js
const getElementCaseInsensitivelyByNameOrId = (nameOrId) => {
    const t = nameOrId.toLowerCase();
    return [...document.querySelectorAll("[id], [name]")].find(e => e.id?.toLowerCase() === t || e.name?.toLowerCase() === t);
}
```